# FileShare Sync SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, file

we have SP 2013 foundation it uses Forms authentication.
We have a file server on the same internal network and I want to sync files between this server and our SP 2013 server. real time if we can or have a sync schedule say that runs each hour.

we have trailed Bamboo, which worked fine. so we bought it. then once we literally put the code in, it stopped working. we have had no end of issues, and its still not fixed.

if it works this product would have been excellent.

is there any other way to acheve what I want to do WITHOUT actually putting the data directly in to the SP 2013 SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage SharePoint Search. Schedule search to crawl the file share. You can set the frequency of crawl (every 30 mins etc.)

You can use SharePoint search results page to display relevant files based on business requirements (Last modified file on top etc.)

This approach avoid duplication and enables users to easily find the content they are looking for.